# Using a C++ lambda expression without parentheses

Tags: c++, lambda

I am learning lambda expressions in c++ and coming from Pascal I tend to leave out parentheses at functions without parameters. So I didn't set them for a lambda expression without parameters and it always returns `1`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){ 
    
    auto test = [](){return "bla";};
 
    std::cout<<test()<<"  "<<test <<'\n';
}
```

Since there also no warnings with `-Wall` is this intended? If so, why is is it `1`?

Comment: `test()` - there are parenthesis here, fyi

Comment: The `1` is printed by the standard `operator<<` conversion taking a `bool`. Same explanation as in the duplicate.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica the dupe suggests this would be special for `qDebug` when actually it is the same with `ostream`s <<. Sorry for the nitpicking, but how about adding a note to the answer, that the effect is not limited to `qDebug`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number - The process of choosing the overload is **exactly** the same. Are we really gonna pretend it's an entirely different issue because the body of the overload prints `true` instead of `1`?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica to the contrary, it is the same issue (not an entierly different one), but it may not be obvious that `qDebug` has the same set of overloads

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number - It doesn't. It has more overloads. But it does have all the same ones as the standard ostream for built-in types.

Comment: Also `std::cout` will print `true` if it's been imbued with `boolalpha`